# wxpython exe not building with pyinstaller

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, exe, pyinstaller

I have a wxpython application that is not building into an exe when I include matplotlib as an import.  For example, my imports in my main py file looks like:

```
import os
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WX')
import wx
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import FigureCanvasWx as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import copy
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled
import wx.lib.agw.pybusyinfo as PBI
```

I am using PyInstaller 1.5.1 (I can't seem to get 2.0 or 2.1 to install right on my machine).  I am also using the great GUI2EXE file to help guide me through setting everything up.  When I compile the code -- it compiles into an executable, but the exe doesn't run.  However, if I comment out all of the matplotlib imports, the exe builds and opens just fine (it just doesn't show any the map I include).  Therefore, I know my issue is in the matplotlib imports.

There is a warning file that attaches when I compile.  It is very long, but the first few lines look like this:

```
W: no module named termios (top-level import by tty)
W: no module named matplotlib.rcParams (top-level import by matplotlib.figure)
W: no module named numpy.not_equal (top-level import by numpy.numarray.ufuncs)
W: no module named setuptools.Command (top-level import by setuptools.command.setopt)
W: no module named numpy.testing.Tester (top-level import by numpy.polynomial)
W: no module named numpy.compat.formatargspec (top-level import by numpy.ma.core)
```

After a bunch of research, this appears to be a hidden imports problem (although I could be wrong).  I looked at the documentation (http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/develop/project/doc/Manual.html#listing-hidden-imports), and did the example with `hooks-matplotlib.figure.py` and inside there I tried `hiddenimports=['matplotlib','figure'].`  I still get the same errors.  Also, I saw in the PyInstaller directory that under the hooks folder there is already Matplotlib.

I can't figure out why I am not building correctly using PyInstaller.  Any thoughts?

For further info, here is my setup script for pyinstaller:

```
data_files = [('AccesstoJson.py', 'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Documents\\MyFolder\\AccesstoJson.py',
              'DATA'), ('pic2.png', 'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Documents\\MyFolder\\pic1.png',
              'DATA'), ('Calculate_Distance.py', 'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Documents\\MyFolder\\Calculate_Distance.py',
              'DATA'), ('pic2.jpg', 'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Documents\\MyFolder\\pic2.jpg',
              'DATA'), ('pic3.png', 'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Documents\\MyFolder\\pic3.png',
              'DATA'), ('Program_Data_2013.json', 'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Documents\\MyFolder\\Program_Data_2013.json',
              'DATA'), ('pic4.ico', 'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Documents\\MyFolder\\pic4.ico',
              'DATA')]

includes = []
excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'email', 'pywin.debugger',
            'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl',
            'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter']
packages = []
dll_excludes = []
dll_includes = []

options = [('v', '', 'OPTION')]

analysis = Analysis(['C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyinstaller-1.5.1\\support\\_mountzlib.py',
           'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyinstaller-1.5.1\\support\\useUnicode.py',
           'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Documents\\MyFolder\\Scheduler_25Oct2013.py'],
                    pathex=['C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\mpl_toolkits\\*', 'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Documents\\MyFolder'],
                    hookspath=['C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy-1.7.1-py2.7-win32.egg'],
                    excludes=excludes)

pyz = PYZ(analysis.pure, level=9)   

executable = EXE( pyz,
                 analysis.scripts + includes + packages + options,
                 analysis.binaries - dll_excludes + dll_includes + data_files,
                 name=r"Scheduler1.exe",
                 debug=False,
                 console=False,
                 strip=False,
                 upx=False,
                 icon=r'C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\MyFolder\pic4.ico',
                 version=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/MatPlotLib

matplotlib needs mpl-data folder to run and this cannot be packaged into exe file. Either manually copy this folder from site-packages or do something like:

```
import matplotlib
...
setup(
    ...
    data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
)
```

in your setup.py for py2exe. it will copy the data_files folder.